# Finding a very close epsilon

Tags: limits, infinity

This is the Question :

> Given the following limits, find $M>0$ such that for every $x>M$ the expression are $\frac13$-close to their limit (in other words, find $M>0$ s.t. for every $x>M$: |f(x)-L|<\frac13$ for the following functions):
>
> (a) $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+2x-3}{x^2-1}=1$

I'm not sure that i am solving this right.
What I did was finding $M = 2/\epsilon$ using the limit defintion.
Then I am asked to make sure that $\epsilon < \frac13$ so  I did $\frac2M \le \frac13$ which gave me $M > 6$. So I am thinking that for the final answer I can choose $M = 6 + \frac2\epsilon$ and that will make sure that the function will stay between $1.333$ to $\frac23$.

My logic is correct or did I just write very weird and uncorrect stuff ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why $M=6+\frac 2\epsilon$ when you said you just need $M>6$ a sentence before? (Actualla, $\frac2M\le \frac13$ leads to simply $M\ge 6$, which allows you to pick $M=6$ straightaway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{x^2+2x-3}{x^2-1}-1=\frac{2x-2}{x^2-1}=\frac2{x+1} $$
provided (which is needed anyway) $x\ne 1$. The desired condition is $\left|\frac2{x+1}\right|<\frac13$, which is equivalent to ($x>-1$ and $x\ne 1$ and $\frac2{x+1}<\frac13$) or ($x<-1$ and $\frac2{x+1}>\frac13$). Per problem statement we are interested only in positive $M$ and hence only in positive $x$. Therefore, we can drop the second branch and consider $\left|\frac2{x+1}\right|<\frac13$ as equivalent to
$$ \frac2{x+1}<\frac13\iff 2<\frac13(x+1)\iff 6<x+1\iff 5<x.$$
This allows us to pick 
$$ M=5.$$
(Fortunately, this automatically gets rid of the problem at $x=1$).
This is the *smallest* possible choice of $M$. As long as the problem statement does not require you to find the smallest possible $M$, any larger value will be just as correct, for example $M=42$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2}{3}<\frac{x^2+2x-3}{x^2-1}<\frac{4}{3} \Rightarrow 2x^2-2<3x^2+6x-9<4x^2-4$. Now seperate it into two inequalities:$\\$
$2x^2-2<3x^2+6x-9 \iff x^2+6x-7>0 \iff x<-7\vee x>1\\
3x^2+6x-9<4x^2-4 \iff x^2-6x+5>0 \iff x<1\vee x>5$

Since $x\rightarrow \infty$ we also need $x>0$ thus we get $x>5$ which gives us $M=5$.